# How can i access to the acumulator of the reducer in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce, reducers

I need to get the value of the accumulator, i get to log but not to recover the value.

Thanks everyone.

Matt.

```js
let seq = [-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4];


var maxSequence = function(arr){
  let valMax = -999999999999999999;
  let result = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    count(spliceArr(arr ,i, arr.length));

  }
}

function spliceArr(arr, index, arrLength){
  return arr.slice(index, arrLength)
}

function count(arr){
    return arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {    
                        console.log(accumulator);   // <= I need this value
                        return accumulator + currentValue 
                      })
}


maxSequence(seq)
```

Comment: keep a separate array for that

Comment: I'd use `map` instead of `reduce` for this operation.

Comment: it's not clear what is your desired output

Comment: So you want `maxSequence` to return something? You are not doing anything with the result of the `count()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the accumulator an array instead, using only its last item in your calculation.

```
function count(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    accumulator.push(+accumulator.slice(-1) + currentValue);
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
}
```

```js
let seq = [-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4];


var maxSequence = function(arr){
  let valMax = -999999999999999999;
  let result = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log('before: ', spliceArr(arr ,i, arr.length));
    console.log('after: ', count(spliceArr(arr ,i, arr.length)));
  }
}

function spliceArr(arr, index, arrLength){
  return arr.slice(index, arrLength)
}

function count(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    accumulator.push(+accumulator.slice(-1) + currentValue);
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
}

maxSequence(seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code you have now, you could push the values to an array and use them as you need.

```
function count(arr){
    let accumulatorArr = [];
    return arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {    
                        // <= now you have an array of accumulator
                        accumulatorArr.push(accumulator);   
                        return accumulator + currentValue 
                      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of the results of the accumulation and not the final result.  It feels like a `map` operation would make more sense.

```js
let seq = [-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4];


var maxSequence = function(arr){
  let valMax = -999999999999999999;
  let result = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log('before: ', spliceArr(arr ,i, arr.length));
    console.log('after: ', count(spliceArr(arr ,i, arr.length)));
  }
}

function spliceArr(arr, index, arrLength){
  return arr.slice(index, arrLength)
}

function count(arr){
    let accumulator = 0;
    return arr.map(currentValue => {
      accumulator += currentValue;
      return accumulator;
    })
}


maxSequence(seq)
```

Comment: Yes Doug thank you're right, but i'll want learn the mechanisme of the reduce function :)